# SAPUI5 JSON Mockdata Date Format

Tags: json, sapui5

I have mockdata setup and one of the values is the date.

"OrderDate": "/Date(1467072000000)/",

I am just wanting to manually change it to todays date so I can see some mockdata on an app I am making changes to.

What format should that look like?

Comment: Open a console and type new Date().getTime() to get now as millis sinc 1970. Btw. SAP WEB IDE has a nice UI to edit mock data, it includes a date picker for date fields

Answer (score 0):

As they mock-up files are mock-up presentations of an OData service, you should format the date in those files as OData properties as well. The [OData spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/#PrimitiveTypes) says this about DateTime fields:

> Edm.DateTime: `"/Date(<ticks>["+" | "-" <offset>)`
>   `ticks` = number of
>   milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970.
>   `offset` = number of minutes to
>   add or subtract

As it is quite difficult to calculate the number of milliseconds since "midnight Jan 1, 1970" by heart, I could recommend this tool to do the math for you:

http://www.epochconverter.com/